# Как разрешить программу в файерволе Windows( netsh.exe ) ?

Tags: windows, firewall, netsh

Здравствуйте.
Можете пожалуйста показать, как можно добавить приложение в список разрешенных программ файервола Windows, используя стандартную утилиту Netsh.exe ? Спасибо.

---

Смотрел вот [этот ресурс](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/947709), но толком не понял, как использовать те команды. А точнее вот эту:

```
netsh firewall add allowedprogram C:\MyApp\MyApp.exe «Мое приложение» ВКЛЮЧИТЬ
```

Comment: Если в один прекрасный момент обнаруживаешь, что заимствуешь решения у пхпешников - это сигнал о том, что что-то сильно не так :-)
ЗЫ: INetFwMgr

Comment: Ну да, у php`шников =)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
netsh advfirewall firewall add rule name="My Application" dir=in action=allow program="C:\MyApp\MyApp.exe" enable=yes
```

В чем проблема была?

Comment: Будьте внимательны! Только из группы с правами администратора

Comment: Огромное спасибо! Вот только одно уточнение - этот код сработает и приложение станет разрешенным в брэндмауэре, если пользователь зашёл, как администратор?

Comment: Да, но чтобы использовать его гибко ознакомьтесь:
[Technet][1]


  [1]: http://technet.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/cc732869(v=ws.10).aspx

Comment: Класс! Спасибо вам огромное! Это именно то, что нужно. Респект)